# How does one get "Young Spirits" achievement?

Tags: achievements, samorost-3

I've finished the game and gotten the `Distilled Spirits` achievement, but how do I get the `Young Spirits` achievement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=651760113), you get it if you "land on the small moon launched from the volcanic planet."